# How to use "or" in equality in clips?

Tags: function, clips

I have to work with this base and delete duplicates.

```
(deffacts MAIN::requirements "Expert Commitee"  (softgoalElement (sgId gen104) (sgQualityAttribute "quality") (sgSujectObject "review") (sgGoalId gen98) (sgActorName "reviewer") (sgBhId gen2))    (softgoalElement (sgId gen107) (sgQualityAttribute "quality") (sgSujectObject "review") (sgGoalId gen96) (sgActorName "chair") (sgBhId gen20))    (softgoalElement (sgId gen109) (sgQualityAttribute "quality") (sgSujectObject "review") (sgGoalId gen97) (sgActorName "committe") (sgBhId gen26))    (softgoalElement (sgId gen110) (sgQualityAttribute "quality") (sgSujectObject "review") (sgGoalId gen98) (sgActorName "reviewer") (sgBhId gen34))    (softgoalElement (sgId gen113) (sgQualityAttribute "quality") (sgSujectObject "article") (sgGoalId gen96) (sgActorName "chair") (sgBhId gen50)))
```

These are the extracted data duplicates:

```
 (gen113)quality [article] 
 (gen111)honest [review] 
 (gen110)quality[review] 
 (gen109)quality [review] 
 (gen108)acknowledge [committee]
 (gen107)quality [review] 
 (gen105)punctuality [plubication]
 (gen104)quality [review]
```

I am using this rule:

```
(defrule Deleting::ruleDeleteSoftgoal  "This rule deletes duplicate softagoal found in the facts base." 

    (declare (salience 58))
    ?fact <- (softgoalElement 
    (sgId ?sgId1)
    (sgSujectObject ?SubjectObjectSg1)      
    (sgQualityAttribute ?QualityAttributeSg1)
    (sgGoalId             ?GoalIdSg1         )
    (sgActorName          ?ActorNameSg1      )
    )
    ?fact2 <- (softgoalElement  
    (sgId ?sgId2)
    (sgSujectObject ?SubjectObjectSg2)      
    (sgQualityAttribute ?QualityAttributeSg2)
    (sgGoalId             ?GoalIdSg2         )  
    (sgActorName          ?ActorNameSg2      ) 
    )

    (test (and (neq ?sgId1 ?sgId2)(eq ?SubjectObjectSg2 ?SubjectObjectSg1)(eq ?QualityAttributeSg2 ?QualityAttributeSg1) 
               (neq ?GoalIdSg2  ?GoalIdSg1 )(neq ?ActorNameSg2  ?ActorNameSg1 )))
    =>
    (retract ?fact2) )
```

However, exist on the same database (sgActorName) and I haven't been able to delete, leaving only a record to the end: I'd have to look like this:

```
(gen113)quality [article]
(gen111)honest [review]
(gen110)quality [review]
(gen108)acknowledge [committee]
(gen105)punctuality [plubication]
```

Can I help me?

Gary,

I've been trying to eliminate repetitions, on this basis, the rule are deleting some duplicate combinations and others don't, I checked the rule and have not found anything that is preventing the exclusion. Can you help me again?

data:

```
(deftemplate synonymoustype "Gets the Type of softgoal"
    (slot type        (type STRING) )
    (slot syntype     (type STRING) )  

)


(deftemplate synonymoustopic "Gets the topic of softgoal"
    (slot topic       (type STRING) )
    (slot syntopic    (type STRING) )
)
```

the rule of exclusion:

```
(defrule ruleDeleteSoftgoal  ""
    (declare (salience 50))
    (synSoftgoal 
       (ttId ?ttId1)
       (synTopic ?syntopic1)      
       (synType ?syntype1))

    ?fact2 <- (synSoftgoal 
                 (ttId ?ttId2)
                 (synTopic ?syntopic2)      
                 (synType ?syntype2))

    (test (and (neq ?ttId1 ?ttId2)
               (eq ?syntopic2 ?syntopic1)
               (eq ?syntype2 ?syntype1)))
    =>
    (retract ?fact2))
```

Base:

```
(deffacts synonymtype  
  (synonymoustype (type  "correct") (syntype "equitable ") ) 
  (synonymoustype (type  "correct") (syntype "legitimate ") ) 
  (synonymoustype (type  "correct") (syntype "proper ") ) 
  (synonymoustype (type  "correct") (syntype "true ") ) 
  (synonymoustype (type  "fair") (syntype "equitable") )
  (synonymoustype (type  "fair") (syntype "legitimate") ) 
  (synonymoustype (type  "fair") (syntype "sincere") ) 
  (synonymoustype (type  "fair") (syntype "straightforward ") ) 
  (synonymoustype (type  "fair") (syntype "trustworthy") ) 
  (synonymoustype (type  "honest") (syntype "sincere") )
  (synonymoustype (type  "honest") (syntype "straightforward") )
  (synonymoustype (type  "honest") (syntype "true") )
  (synonymoustype (type  "honest") (syntype "trustworthy") )
  (synonymoustype (type  "acknowledge") (syntype "accept") ))

 (deffacts synonymtopic
    (synonymoustopic (topic "evaluation") (syntopic "appraisal") ) 
    (synonymoustopic (topic "review") (syntopic "analysis") )
    (synonymoustopic (topic "review") (syntopic "audit") ) )
```

Result:

```
(gen42)accept   [appraisal]
(gen41)trustworthy   [appraisal] - DEVERIA TER UMA SÓ
(gen40)true   [appraisal] - DEVERIA TER UMA SÓ
(gen39)straightforward   [appraisal] - DEVERIA TER UMA SÓ
(gen38)sincere   [appraisal] - DEVERIA TER UMA SÓ
(gen37)trustworthy   [appraisal]
(gen36)straightforward    [appraisal]
(gen35)sincere   [appraisal]
(gen34)legitimate   [appraisal] - DEVERIA TER UMA SÓ
(gen33)equitable   [appraisal] -DEVERIA TER UMA SÓ
(gen32)true    [appraisal]
(gen31)proper    [appraisal]
(gen30)legitimate    [appraisal]
(gen29)equitable    [appraisal]
(gen28)accept   [analysis]
(gen27)trustworthy   [analysis
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your criteria for removing duplicates is not clear. One possible solution is to check that either sgGoalId, sgActorName, or sgBhId is different:

```
(defrule ruleDeleteSoftgoal  

    (softgoalElement 
       (sgId ?sgId1)
       (sgSujectObject ?SubjectObjectSg1)      
       (sgQualityAttribute ?QualityAttributeSg1)
       (sgGoalId ?GoalIdSg1)
       (sgActorName ?ActorNameSg1)
       (sgBhId ?sgBhId1))

    ?fact2 <- (softgoalElement
                 (sgId ?sgId2)
                 (sgSujectObject ?SubjectObjectSg2)      
                 (sgQualityAttribute ?QualityAttributeSg2)
                 (sgGoalId ?GoalIdSg2)  
                 (sgActorName ?ActorNameSg2)
                 (sgBhId ?sgBhId2))

    (test (and (neq ?sgId1 ?sgId2)
               (eq ?SubjectObjectSg2 ?SubjectObjectSg1)
               (eq ?QualityAttributeSg2 ?QualityAttributeSg1) 
               (or (neq ?GoalIdSg2 ?GoalIdSg1 )
                   (neq ?ActorNameSg2 ?ActorNameSg1)
                   (neq ?sgBhId2 ?sgBhId1))))
    =>
    (retract ?fact2))
```

Another is to remove the checks on sgGoalId and sgActorName.

```
(defrule ruleDeleteSoftgoal  

    (softgoalElement 
       (sgId ?sgId1)
       (sgSujectObject ?SubjectObjectSg1)      
       (sgQualityAttribute ?QualityAttributeSg1))

    ?fact2 <- (softgoalElement
                 (sgId ?sgId2)
                 (sgSujectObject ?SubjectObjectSg2)      
                 (sgQualityAttribute ?QualityAttributeSg2))

    (test (and (neq ?sgId1 ?sgId2)
               (eq ?SubjectObjectSg2 ?SubjectObjectSg1)
               (eq ?QualityAttributeSg2 ?QualityAttributeSg1)))
    =>
    (retract ?fact2))
```

Both produce the final output you want.

Gary, this is the order of execution complete:

```
(deftemplate synonymoustype "Gets the Type of softgoal"
    (slot type        (type STRING) )
    (slot syntype     (type STRING) )  

)


(deftemplate synonymoustopic "Gets the topic of softgoal"
    (slot topic       (type STRING) )
    (slot syntopic    (type STRING) )
)

(deftemplate synSoftgoal "synsoftgoal receives synonyms for softgoals extracted from the base facts of (Cunha, 2014)"
    (slot ttId        (type SYMBOL) )
    (slot synTopic    (type STRING) )
    (slot synType     (type STRING) )
)
```

carry the base:

```
(deffacts synonymtype  
  (synonymoustype (type  "correct") (syntype "equitable ") ) 
  (synonymoustype (type  "correct") (syntype "legitimate ") ) 
  (synonymoustype (type  "correct") (syntype "proper ") ) 
  (synonymoustype (type  "correct") (syntype "true ") ) 
  (synonymoustype (type  "fair") (syntype "equitable") )
  (synonymoustype (type  "fair") (syntype "legitimate") ) 
  (synonymoustype (type  "fair") (syntype "sincere") ) 
  (synonymoustype (type  "fair") (syntype "straightforward ") ) 
  (synonymoustype (type  "fair") (syntype "trustworthy") ) 
  (synonymoustype (type  "honest") (syntype "sincere") )
  (synonymoustype (type  "honest") (syntype "straightforward") )
  (synonymoustype (type  "honest") (syntype "true") )
  (synonymoustype (type  "honest") (syntype "trustworthy") )
  (synonymoustype (type  "acknowledge") (syntype "accept") ))

 (deffacts synonymtopic
 (synonymoustopic (topic "evaluation") (syntopic "appraisal") ) 
 (synonymoustopic (topic "review") (syntopic "analysis") )
 (synonymoustopic (topic "review") (syntopic "audit") ) )
```

run these tree rules:

```
(defrule ruleAssertSynsoftgoal "extracts the data from the base and inserts in synSoftgoal"

    (synonymoustype
    (type            ?type    )
    (syntype         ?syntype ))

    (synonymoustopic
    (topic           ?topic   )
    (syntopic        ?syntopic))
     =>
    (assert (synSoftgoal (ttId(gensym)) (synType ?syntype)(synTopic ?syntopic) ))



)

(defrule ruleDeleteSoftgoal  "delete duplicate"

    (synSoftgoal 
       (ttId ?ttId1)
       (synTopic ?syntopic1)      
       (synType ?syntype1))

    ?fact2 <- (synSoftgoal 
                 (ttId ?ttId2)
                 (synTopic ?syntopic2)      
                 (synType ?syntype2))

    (test (and (neq ?ttId1 ?ttId2)
               (eq ?syntopic2 ?syntopic1)
               (eq ?syntype2 ?syntype1)))
    =>
    (retract ?fact2))




   (defrule rulePrintsTypeTopic "prints the base synSoftgoal"

         (declare (salience 65))
         (synSoftgoal 
         (ttId ?tId )
         (synType ?Type)
         (synTopic ?Topic)      

         )
        =>
         (printout t  "Id:(" ?tId ") SynSoftgoal: "?Type" [" ?Topic "]" crlf) 
    )
```

Result:

```
(gen42)accept   [appraisal]
(gen41)trustworthy   [appraisal] - DEVERIA TER UMA SÓ
(gen40)true   [appraisal] - DEVERIA TER UMA SÓ
(gen39)straightforward   [appraisal] - DEVERIA TER UMA SÓ
(gen38)sincere   [appraisal] - DEVERIA TER UMA SÓ
(gen37)trustworthy   [appraisal]
(gen36)straightforward    [appraisal]
(gen35)sincere   [appraisal]
(gen34)legitimate   [appraisal] - DEVERIA TER UMA SÓ
(gen33)equitable   [appraisal] -DEVERIA TER UMA SÓ
(gen32)true    [appraisal]
(gen31)proper    [appraisal]
(gen30)legitimate    [appraisal]
(gen29)equitable    [appraisal]
(gen28)accept   [analysis]
(gen27)trustworthy   [analysis
```

Comment: It's difficult to figure out how to fix your program when you just include code fragments rather than a complete example that can be run to reproduce the results you're seeing.

Comment: Still unreproducible with the recent edits. The format of the results you listed don't even match the printout statements from your code which look like this: Id:(gen4) SynSoftgoal: proper  [audit]

Comment: Gary, is that in combination she combines each type with all topics, and how the response would be very great just put part of the results. She makes all kinds combined with each topic having at the end of the process elicited synsoftgoal 42 and among them cited by you. If you can send an email sending everything complete for you. Thanks